# why css is not imported in react js making date picker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement this date picker
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-16-bootstrap-date-picker
I am able to implement this but my date picker is not look like same as show in example .I think my css file is not loaded why ?

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/r1ox70mrq

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        ddd
        <DatePicker id="example-datepicker" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just you need to add bootstrap style to your index.html in your react project like this:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

check [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/6yxo4r57pw).

Also you can check this [reference](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add bootstrap css.
For reference https://github.com/pushtell/react-bootstrap-date-picker/blob/master/example/app.jsx